# New Android upload to Play Console code signing error

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-console, android-keystore

It's been a while since I submitted an app to google play, but when I recently tried, I got the following signing error:

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are enrolled in Play App Signing, you should sign your APK or Android App Bundle with a new key before you upload it.

I have created my build with

```
% ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

as I always have.

I am not aware that I have changed anything signing-related on my system since my last successful upload.
What *has* changed is:

- Android Studio Version
- Google play looks different

What I have tried:

- verified the `debuggable` is not set and thus defaults to `false`
- ran `./gradlew clean` first

I have tried to to find this particular error on the web but to no avail.
What am I doing wrong?